# KP-monospaced with LuaLaTeX

Tags: fontspec, kpfonts

how do I set KP-monospaced font to be used as tt font with fontspec?

I tried this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{KP-monospaced}
\begin{document}
\texttt{120 test}
\end{document}
```

But it does not work

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Do you have the fonts installed in opentype or truetype format? As far as I can tell, TeX Live includes type1 versions but nothing else, in which case you probably need to load them in the 'traditional' way rather than using `fontspec` i.e. `\usepackage{}` or specific commands for just the monospaced font, for example.

Comment: @cfr I only have the version that comes with the CTAN package. don't know what that is. How do I load the package in the traditional way? If I add `usepackage{kpfonts}` nothing changes and the tt font is not in kp-monospaced.

Comment: It works for me if I delete the `fontspec` and `\set...` lines.

Comment: @cfr No, sorry, I was not clear. I need to load fontspec for other purposes in my document. So my question is: how to load the tt font in a traditional way while using fontspec?

Comment: Ah. That's more complex as you need to enforce a non-unicode encoding against the will of `fontspec`. See my answer below. (Code doesn't work well in comments!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not certain this is the right way to do it but the following seems to work for me, with very minimal testing. ***Caveat emptor...***

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\ttfamily{%
  \not@math@alphabet\ttfamily\mathtt
  \fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily\ttdefault\selectfont}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{jkptt}
\begin{document}
  \texttt{120 test}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is the instruction `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` necessary?

Comment: Ok, with a preliminary test it works. thank you (can't upvote)

Comment: @Mico I'm not sure. This test worked without it but I was worried that it might be necessary for something more subtle I wasn't aware of. Would it be safe to remove it?

Comment: One commonly-given pieces of advice when using LuaLaTeX is *not* to load the `fontenc` and `inputenc` packages. Your MWE definitely seems to work without the `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` instruction.

Comment: @Mico That is the general rule, yes. However, my understanding is that `fontenc` is sometimes appropriate for use with Xe/LuaLaTeX, but that you have to be careful. Typically, it is a bad idea but typically, you are not using the `T1` encoding because using the `T1` encoding is a bad idea. In this case, though, you **have** to rely on the `T1` encoding. So we are already outside the remit of standard recommendations. I can't find anything yet which omitting it breaks, but I'm not at all sure that there is no such thing!

Comment: @Mico It seems that `fontspec` loads `fontenc`. (Pointed out by TorbjørnT.) So the question is whether loading it with `T1` is a good way to handle this case or whether there is a better option...